# Postgres using the primary key index as a covering index

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, indexing

I'm wondering if, in Postgres, there are any downsides to piggybacking extra fields into the index implicitly created for the primary key in order to not have to create more indices.

This is a common technique in creating clustered indices in SQL Server.

**edit**

Good [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes) on Postgres indexing. Seems Postgres indexing dynamics are different to SQL server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible.

PostgreSQL cannot "include" columns without making them "active" in the index.

Currently PostgreSQL does not support index only scans. This will be included in the upcoming 9.2 release though.

But adding columns to an index that you don't need might impose a performance penalty for updates because a non-indexed column is much more efficient to update than an indexed column.

Comment: Hmm but if the id is unique that means the entire triple is unique ?

Comment: ;) I was worried that Postgres was doing some funkey stuff.

Comment: Oh wow, are you saying that Postgres doesn't do covering indexes ?

Comment: @Hassan Syed: In 9.2 Postgres will have ability to pull data out of indexes instead of having to read the index and then go to the table pages to pull actual data. With  9.2 you should be able to created covered indexes.

Comment: @HassanSyed Correct, PostgreSQL doesn't support covering indexes, though limited support will exist in 9.2

Comment: @HassanSyed: Regarding "uniqueness": Extending the PK index allows anyone to insert multiple rows with the same real PK. Using something like `SERIAL` cannot prevent this, because this is only a default which can be overridden in the`INSERT`.